# How do i call my Unit Test function in PySpark Code?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a unit test module in my PySpark code but not sure how to execute it.

Here is my code which simply reads one dataframe which has only 2 columns Day and Amount. The script is saved as test.py  I am simply doing sum(amount) on “Day”. Here is the code-

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pytest
import unittest

def main():
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp").config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","2").getOrCreate()
    #Start ETL
    data = extract_data(spark)
    data_transformed = transform_data(data)

    # log the success and terminate Spark application
    spark.stop()
    return None

# Extract Data
def extract_data(spark):
    df = (spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header","true").csv("myfile.txt"))
    return df

# Transform Data
def transform_data(df):
    df_transformed = (df.groupBy("Day").sum("Amount").withColumnRenamed("sum(Amount)","total_amt").select("Day","total_amt"))
    return df_transformed

pytestmark = pytest.mark.usefixtures("spark")
def my_test_func(self):
    test_input = [Row(Day=1, Amount =10),\
                  Row(Day=1, Amount =20)]
    input_df = spark.createDataFrame(test_input)
    result = transform_data(input_df).select("total_amt").collect()[0]
    expected_result = 30
    self.assertEqual(result, expected_result)
    print("test done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new to PySpark and have couple questions-

1. Is my unit test function declaration correctly in above code? If not, how to declare it?
2. How do i execute my_test_func? Where should i call it? I want to run this script simply with spark-submit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your spark unit test in different folder.
For example,

```
src
 +--jobs
      +-- job1

tests
 +--__jobs
      +---job1
```

Then the following is how you write your testcase

```py
class TestJob1 \
            (unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        Start Spark, define config and path to test data
        """
        self.spark=SparkSession.builder
                               .appName("MyApp")
                               .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","2")
                               .getOrCreate()
        self.job1 = Job1(self.spark)


    def tearDown(self):
        """
        Stop Spark
        """
        self.spark.stop()

    def test_yourtest_code(self):

        test_input = [Row(Day=1, Amount =10),
                      Row(Day=1, Amount =20)]
        input_df = spark.createDataFrame(test_input)
        result = transform_data(input_df).select("total_amt").collect()[0]
        expected_result = 30
        self.assertEqual(result, expected_result)
        print("test done")
```

You can run test case

```sh
python -m unittest jobs.TestJob1
python -m unittest jobs.TestJob1.test_yourtest_code
```

Comment: Thanks, how should i call it for execution ?

Comment: I use pyCharm can execute each test function.   You can run command line by
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass
python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method

Comment: Thanks Howie, i was able to run it end to end.